# Преобразовать массив объектов

Tags: javascript

Ребят, помогите преобразовать такой вот массив объектов.

Ключ category1 сейчас вложенный, нужно перебрать так, чтобы поменялась структура, как во втором случае

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "slug": "slug-slug",
        "name": "Name1",
        "category": {
            "id": "1122",
            "name": "Name2",
            "slug": "slug-slug1",
            "iso": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "223",
        "slug": "slug-slug",
        "name": "Name2",
        "category": {
            "id": "2122",
            "name": "Name3",
            "slug": "slug-slug2",
            "iso": null
        }
    },
];
```

в такой

```
[
    "category": {
        "id": "1122",
        "name": "Name2",
        "slug": "slug-slug1",
        "iso": null,
        "category1" : {
            "id": "123",
            "slug": "slug-slug",
            "name": "Name1",
        }
    },
    "category": {
        "id": "2122",
        "name": "Name3",
        "slug": "slug-slug2",
        "iso": null,
        "category1" : {
            "id": "223",
            "slug": "slug-slug",
            "name": "Name2",
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: чем отличаются массивы? С чем возникли проблемы?

Comment: Для преобразование одного массива в другой можно использовать метод [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: ключи category1 сейчас вложенный, нужно перебрать так, чтобы поменялась структура, как во втором случае

Comment: Добавь это описание в сам вопрос.

Comment: я новичок, способы перебора понятны, а вот как реализовать данную задачу, пока не знаю

Comment: Второй массив не валидный js массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант, если нужно можно исключить подобъект.

```js
const array = [{
    "id": "123",
    "slug": "slug-slug",
    "name": "Name1",
    "category": {
      "id": "1122",
      "name": "Name2",
      "slug": "slug-slug1",
      "iso": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "223",
    "slug": "slug-slug",
    "name": "Name2",
    "category": {
      "id": "2122",
      "name": "Name3",
      "slug": "slug-slug2",
      "iso": null
    }
  },
];

var newArray = array.map(function(el) {
  let newObj = Object.assign({}, el.category);
  newObj.category1 = el;
  delete newObj.category1.category;
  return newObj;
})

console.log(newArray);
```